# iOS: Select output on AVAudioSession with headphones attached

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to change the audio route on an iPhone app : with no headphones attached everything works fine, I can select between BuiltInReceiver or BuiltInSpeaker

But when I attach headphones to the phone, I cannot change the speaker output anymore.
Furthermore the behavior is different when the headphones have been attached before the app starts (speaker output still works), or after the app started (output only on headphones).

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:nil];

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.